# Container.DataItem works in C# not in VB.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

This line of code

```
((Matches)Container.DataItem).MatchID
```

works in C# but in VB.NET, when used in a Repeater, I get the error

'Matches' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
DirectCast(Container.DataItem,Matches).MatchID
```

Comment: Awesome Jared..Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1):

That's because it is C# and not VB.NET.

I think the cast syntax for VB.NET looks something like:

```
CType(Container.DataItem, Matches).EmpID
```

but no doubt a VB.NET expert will chime in if this is wrong.